# How do I pass data from nodejs to an html file in the dirname folder

Tags: node.js, express

What I am trying to do is get data from a database and render it into a html page, I have the data from the database but I dont know how to pass that data into html. Below is the part of the code that I want to use to pass data.

```
router.get('/',function(req,res){
    connection.connect((err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('this is the home route');

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM products', (err,rows) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        // const {barcode,product_description,quantity,expiry_date,days} = req.body this is the data present in rows
      
        console.log('Data received from Db:');
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'),rows);
        
        console.log(rows);
      });
      
})
```

});

This is the html file that is in the root directory

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>{{rows}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought puting rows that way would magically place my data there. How would I go about inserting my data to this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They key thing here is that it **isn't** an HTML file. It is a template that you generate an HTML file from.

Express supports [template engines](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) and their use is covered in the Express guide.

Pick one.

The syntax you are using looks like [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) but there are plenty of others.

Then you can find [plenty of guides to combining them](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=express+mustache+javascript&atb=v376-1&ia=web).

This boils down to:

1. Configure the view engine
2. Use `render` instead of `sendFile`

---

```js
const mustacheExpress = require('mustache-express');

// ...

app.set('views', `${__dirname}/views`);
app.set('view engine', 'mustache');
app.engine('mustache', mustacheExpress());

// ...

router.get('/',function(req,res){
    // ...
    res.render("index", { rows} );
    // ...
});
```